# How do I remove this specific linker error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

```
    int match(int page,Mat img_frame){
Mat des_frame;
std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_frame;
std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
detector.detect( img_frame, kp_frame );
extractor.compute(img_frame,kp_frame,des_frame);
std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
if(page<0)
    return 0;
switch(pageNumber)
{
    case 0:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[0], des_frame, matches, 2);
        break;
    case 2:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[1], des_frame, matches, 2);
        //cout<<"matcigpage23";
        break;
    case 4:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[2], des_frame, matches, 2);
        break;
    case 6:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[3], des_frame, matches, 2);
        break;
    case 8:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[4], des_frame, matches, 2);
        break;
    case 10:
        matcher.knnMatch(des_page[5], des_frame, matches, 2);
        break;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_frame.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }
    return good_matches.size();
}
```

I have a function like this in my '.cpp'. When I compile this in Visual Studio 2010, I get a linker error like this:

> 1>realtime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::SIFT::SIFT(int,int,double,double,double)" (??0SIFT@cv@@QAE@HHNNN@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'detector''(void)" (??*_Edetector@@YAXXZ)
>
> 1>realtime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams::KDTreeIndexParams(int)" (??0KDTreeIndexParams@flann@cv@@QAE@H@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'matcher''(void)" (??*_Ematcher@@YAXXZ)
>
> 1>realtime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::flann::SearchParams::SearchParams(int,float,bool)" (??0SearchParams@flann@cv@@QAE@HM_N@Z) referenced in function "void _*cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'matcher''(void)" (??*_Ematcher@@YAXXZ)
>
> 1>realtime.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams(void)" (??1IndexParams@flann@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __thiscall cv::flann::IndexParams::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GIndexParams@flann@cv@@QAEPAXI@Z)
>
> 1>C:\Users\vinit\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\mynewopencv\Debug\mynewopencv.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

I am new Visual Studio and I will really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `opencv` and not linking against its library (.lib file).

Right click on your project in the **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties** from the context menu.

Under **Configuration Properties > Linker > Input** add the .lib file for `opencv` to **Additional Dependencies**.

Answer (score 1):

you need to link the library in the visual studio editor.

Please right click on  **project** in the Solution Explorer and select **Properties** from the menu.

Under Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies add the (.lib) such as-opencv_calib3d220d.lib
     opencv_contrib220d.lib
     opencv_core220d.lib
     opencv_features2d220d.lib

and then do Apply, I hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

For the Flann Matcher you need to link: opencv_flannXXXd.lib